# What is the process to include a progress Bar before an activity launches

Tags: android, progress-bar

Am trying to include a progessbar in my app before launching my activity.
If any one knows the perfect implementaion let me know.Am tried but not getting the desired solution.
Because of this issue m not able to work further.Plz i need help.

I know the Process how to include the progress Dialog but i want to include ProgessBar.What i really need to do.

M sharing my code that i hv tried:

```
  package com.example.demo1;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.widget.ProgressBar;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

 private ProgressBar mProgress;
 private int mProgressStatus = 0;

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }

        private int doWork() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
     }).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `splash screen`

Comment: post you tries / efforts

Comment: @utility i have shared the code that i tried to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**You can include splash activity like this:->**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        context = this;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                  
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);       
               finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dzone.com/articles/android-example-progress-bar see if this helps... They have shown buffering progress bar example also...I dont know which one you need but this can help you chose any of them as per requirements...